# How to set android background color into Fragments

Tags: java, android, xml, background-color

I have a fragment into activity with `WebView` and `TextView`.

[image]

Here you can see 2 background colors. WebView's background color is white, but the others part color (i singled them out with black rectangles) is gray. I think its standard Light Theme color and I want to change it to white(like in WebView) I tried a lot of things to do this: `android: background` in Fragment Layout and in Activity Layout, I tried

`<item name="android:windowBackground">@color/backgroundColor</item>` in Activity and App Theme.

How can I set background color to white?

Fragment code:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
    android:background="@color/backgroundColor"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/wb_for_task"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="0dp"></WebView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_in_task_informatics"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Activity code:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:background="@color/backgroundColor"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:theme="@style/CoolTheme"
    tools:context=".activities.MainActivity"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/backgroundColor"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/app_bar_in_main"
            layout="@layout/app_bar" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:background="@color/backgroundColor"
            android:id="@+id/container_in_Main"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"></FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_viewInMain"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="#FFFF"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Themes (the first one is AppTheme):

```
<style name="CustomToolbarStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/backgroundColor</item>
        <item name="elevation">0dp</item>
    </style>
    <style name="CoolTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="android:background">@color/backgroundColor</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/backgroundColor</item>
    </style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your theme isn't applied. Set it in the manifest file on application or activity level:

```
 <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:theme="@style/CoolTheme">
```

Your scrollview has margins on the left and right side, where the fragment background is visible. You should use paddings instead of margins for scrollviews.

Reference: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/themes

Answer (score 1):

Just add **padding** instead of **margin** to the ScrollView in your fragment.`

Here's the changed code:

```xml
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingStart="15dp"
    android:paddingEnd="15dp"
    android:background="@color/backgroundColor"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/wb_for_task"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="0dp"></WebView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_in_task_informatics"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```